# What program to use for incremental backup of large single file

Tags: backup, synchronization, incremental-backup

I'm looking for a program to make incremental backups of one large file (3GB) on windows systems over internet.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: More recently, in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: [How to back-up one big file with small changes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265523/13260)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to keep a remote copy of the file then using something based on rsync will probably work for you. Rsync only copies the parts of the file that have changed so it can reduce the amount of data you have to to copy.

For windows you could use [deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) or [syncrify](http://web.synametrics.com/Syncrify.htm).

Comment: How does the sender determine what parts are changed in comparison to the backup version? Is there something linke piecewise hash-files? I do not want to read back the whole file only to check what parts got changed (bandwith)

Comment: @schoetbi read the rsync protocol documentation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a windows share as target for the backup. So I can not use the rsync protocol. I was looking for a way like torrent is doing things (picewise checksums to update only changed blocks within the file).

Comment: rsync is actually incremental transfer to keep a full backup. doesn't answer the question how to keep incremental backup.

Answer (score 7):

you can also give [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) a try. it has version for windows too.

i use it for nightly backups of [in total] few hundreds GB of data.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest rsync.  It's the standard tool for this sort of thing, and I gather it works on Windows as well.